# Remove first N lines of file

Tags: go

I was wondering how I can remove the first N lines of a specific file **efficiently**.

Of course, we can load the complete file into memory, then remove the first N lines and write the complete changed contents to the file.

But, I was wondering if there is a way to make this more effective compared to just loading all contents in memory.

Answer (score 7):

Filesystems doesn't support deleting from arbitrary locations of a file, so you at least need to re-write the entire file yourself. The common way to implement what you need is to

- Open a temporary file,
- read small pieces from the original file, e.g. one line at a time in your case
- Write only lines you want to retain in the original file to the temporary file
- rename the temporary file to the original filename when done.

Comment: I'm afraid that's the only performing solution, I was thinking likely right after posting the question.

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way to do this is read the file backwards.

```
/*
    This package implements funcationality similar to the UNIX command tail.
    It prints out the last "x" many lines of a file, usually 10.
    The number of lines in a file is determined by counting newline (\n) characters.
    This can be use either from CLI or imported into other projects.
*/

package main

import (
    "errors"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
)

var (
    //DEFINE FLAG DEFAULTS
    filename = ""
    numLines = 10

    //ErrNoFilename is thrown when the path the the file to tail was not given
    ErrNoFilename = errors.New("You must provide the path to a file in the \"-file\" flag.")

    //ErrInvalidLineCount is thrown when the user provided 0 (zero) as the value for number of lines to tail
    ErrInvalidLineCount = errors.New("You cannot tail zero lines.")
)

//GET FLAGS FROM CLI
func init() {
    flag.StringVar(&filename, "file", "", "Filename to get last lines of text from.")
    flag.IntVar(&numLines, "n", numLines, "Number of lines to get from end of file.")
    flag.Parse()
}

//MAIN FUNCTIONALITY OF APP
//make sure filename (path to file) was given
//run it through the tailing function
//print the output to stdout
func main() {
    //TAIL
    text, err := GoTail(filename, numLines)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    //DONE
    fmt.Print(text)
    return
}

//GoTail IS THE FUNCTION THAT ACTUALLY DOES THE "TAILING"
//this can be used this package is imported into other golang projects
func GoTail(filename string, numLines int) (string, error) {
    //MAKE SURE FILENAME IS GIVEN
    //actually, a path to the file
    if len(filename) == 0 {
        return "", ErrNoFilename
    }

    //MAKE SURE USER WANTS TO GET AT LEAST ONE LINE
    if numLines == 0 {
        return "", ErrInvalidLineCount
    }

    //OPEN FILE
    file, err := os.Open(filename)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    defer file.Close()

    //SEEK BACKWARD CHARACTER BY CHARACTER ADDING UP NEW LINES
    //offset must start at "-1" otherwise we are already at the EOF
    //"-1" from numLines since we ignore "last" newline in a file
    numNewLines := 0
    var offset int64 = -1
    var finalReadStartPos int64
    for numNewLines <= numLines-1 {
        //seek to new position in file
        startPos, err := file.Seek(offset, 2)
        if err != nil {
            return "", err
        }

        //make sure start position can never be less than 0
        //aka, you cannot read from before the file starts
        if startPos == 0 {
            //set to -1 since we +1 to this below
            //the position will then start from the first character
            finalReadStartPos = -1
            break
        }

        //read the character at this position
        b := make([]byte, 1)
        _, err = file.ReadAt(b, startPos)
        if err != nil {
            return "", err
        }

        //ignore if first character being read is a newline
        if offset == int64(-1) && string(b) == "\n" {
            offset--
            continue
        }

        //if the character is a newline
        //add this to the number of lines read
        //and remember position in case we have reached our target number of lines
        if string(b) == "\n" {
            numNewLines++
            finalReadStartPos = startPos
        }

        //decrease offset for reading next character
        //remember, we are reading backward!
        offset--
    }

    //READ TO END OF FILE
    //add "1" here to move offset from the newline position to first character in line of text
    //this position should be the first character in the "first" line of data we want
    endPos, err := file.Seek(int64(-1), 2)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    b := make([]byte, (endPos+1)-finalReadStartPos)
    _, err = file.ReadAt(b, finalReadStartPos+1)
    if err == io.EOF {
        return string(b), nil
    } else if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    //special case
    //if text is read, then err == io.EOF should hit
    //there should *never* not be an error above
    //so this line should never return
    return "**No error but no text read.**", nil
}
```

In the console you must type : `gotail -file <filename> -n=<number of lines>`
So with this you can read the last number of lines from the end of the file. If you want all lines except the first 10 lines, then i will alter this code.

Comment: I wonder if you don't miss out on changes when a log-file is heavily written, when rewriting the file without the first N lines. In the time that this script takes to process the input file, the file itself could have been changed. This could result in losing a some data.

Since you're returning the contents of the tailed data with `GoTail()` I can imagine (depending on the file being inspected), this could be heavily consuming memory.

Comment: @Dygnus I updated the code solving the issue you pointed to me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do something akin to log truncation and rotation?

A common pattern that might help you would be to split logs across multiple files and overwrite or delete files in the order they were created.

For example you might have `2018-09-09.log.txt` or `log.1.txt` and rotate to a new log file every hour. That way older files could be deleted to free up space.

Other than that, I don't think there is a specific way to remove early lines of a file in Go without rewriting the remainder of the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the total number of lines in the file using `wc -l <fileName>` let it be `x`, and suppose u want to read all lines except first 1000 then use `tail -n<x-1000> <fileName>`.

An efficient way would be to use the sed. See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138398/how-to-get-lines-10-to-100-from-a-200-line-file-into-a-new-file) answer