# golang: Monitor (and read) files open for writing

Tags: file, go

I have some .log files and want to monitor if any data is appended to any of them to collect that data into a DB.
How do I open an opened-for-writing file and how do I monitor for new lines/changes?
Thank you.

Comment: Maybe this https://github.com/hpcloud/tail you want

Comment: You have to get the tail of the logfile (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52247755/remove-first-n-lines-of-file), check if the date&time exists in the DB, if not, store it in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this small piece of code that will monitor for file change and if detected, run the function you passed to it.

```
func watchFileAndRun(filePath string, fn func()) error {
    defer func() { r := recover(); if r != nil { logCore("ERROR","Error:watching file:",  r) } }()
    fn()
    initialStat, err := os.Stat(filePath)
    checkErr(err)
    for {
        stat, err := os.Stat(filePath)
        checkErr(err)
        if stat.Size() != initialStat.Size() || stat.ModTime() != initialStat.ModTime() {
            fn()
            initialStat, err = os.Stat(filePath)
            checkErr(err)
        }
        time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
    }
    return nil
}
```

To call this function where `loadEnv` is a function:

```
go watchFileAndRun("config.json", loadEnv)
```

Some Notes:
`go watchFileAndRun()` will run the routing asynchronously. IE in the background.
checkErr is my own function you can simply put a standard
`if err != nil {fmt.printf("Something went wrong",err)}` in its place.
and the defer first line is to prevent the program crashing the main if something went wrong. You could nest it deeper if you wanted to make this function more resilient.
Hope it helps someone. and its smaller than the nsnotify plug in which to be frank I could get working either.